# Live streaming server with multiple radio channels

Tags: shoutcast, icecast, liquidsoap

I want to create a solution where I will have around 1000 people providing real-time speeches to their followers. In each talk-room there will be atmost fifty listeners. Only followers to a particular person will be able to hear the concerned person speaking.

I have installed an `icecast` in my dedicated server.

Can `icecast` support 1000 `sourcepoints` ( all of them streaming real-time using a microphone in their pc)? What hardware configurations will I need to support this?

Do I have to install any other software to encode the media from these concurrent source points?

Are there any javascript web-players which deep-connect to icecast, so that the listeners can listen to the streaming in our website?

Lastly are there any javascript based broadcasting software. I am aware of `BUTT` and `Winamp`, but both are not embeddable softwares.

What broadcasting software, webplayer software and web-based management software would you recommend that you think will be needed for such a deployment?

And, lastly what is the best web-based tool to configure these `sourcepoints`, if there is any to do so?

Comment: What are your latency requirements?  Reasonably real-time I'm sure, but if the listeners heard the broadcast say 10 seconds after the person said something, would that be fine?  You can save a great deal of money and simplify this whole setup, if that's true.

Comment: @Brad Yes if there is a latency upto 10/15 seconds theat will not be an issue as the listener would really have no clue that there is a delay in broadcasting.